# Summarize all costs and show the result in different places of the document

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing

Let's say there is a large document in which the costs for different expenses are listed in different places. At every point where these costs are listed, I would like to have not only the costs themselves, but also an overview of how much budget is still available. Taking into account all the costs indicated in the document, including those that appear after it in the document.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mylabel[2]{\def\@currentlabel{#2}\phantomsection\label{mylabel:#1}}
\newcommand\myref[1]{\ref{mylabel:#1}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{FixMoney}
\setcounter{FixMoney}{1000}
\newcounter{SaveValue}
\setcounter{SaveValue}{\value{FixMoney}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\calcCosts}[1]{%
\bgroup
\newcount\PP
\PP=#1 %Piece Price
\setcounter{SaveValue}{\inteval{\value{SaveValue}-\the\PP}}%
\mylabel{overall}{\the\value{SaveValue}}Piece price:\,\the\PP\,€ / Money left overall \myref{overall}\,€)
\egroup}
\makeatother
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\calcCosts{3}\\
\calcCosts{30}\\
\calcCosts{400}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**
[image: Output]

The output is exactly what I would expect and what I would achieve. I have the cost of something on the left and the remaining budget on the right.

**BUT**

I get the following warning!

> Label `mylabel:overall' multiply defined.

Now the question arises whether my approach of using `\label` for this purpose is really correct, or whether the same functionality can be achieved in a different way.

Comment: Do you really want to waste/allocate another `\count`-register as `\PP` with each instance of `\calcCosts`?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I don't know how to prevent that… I hoped, that the \group encapsulation will prevent this.

Comment: On my system, after compiling, the .log-file contains messages `\PP=\count197`, `\PP=\count198`, `\PP=\count199`, which indicates that each instance of `\calcCosts` does allocate another `\count`-register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a mechanism where you can specify via optional argument where to place the anchor for hyperlinks and the cross-referencing-label does what you want.

(You seem to want not the Euro symbol from the European Commission (that would be `\euro` after loading eurosym) but from the European Computer Modern Fonts.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% \euro - euro-symbol which complies to the symbol suggested and
% and copyrighted(!) by the European Commission -
% <https://european-union.europa.eu/institutions-law-budget/euro/design_en> :
\usepackage{eurosym}  

% In correspondence
% <https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63127536#63127536>
% David Carlisle revealed:
% Euro-symbol of European Computer Modern Fonts (ec - Computer
% modern fonts in T1 and TS1 encodings <https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ec>);
% in other words: Joerg Knappen's guess of what the euro symbol would be:
\newcommand\CMReuro{{%
  \fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont
  \symbol{191}%
  %\texteuro
}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn\@ifundefined{inteval}{\cs_new_eq:NN \inteval \int_eval:n}{}\ExplSyntaxOff
%--Basic Infrastructure----------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\InitializeNewKindOfBudget[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\expandafter{\csname(BudgetNameSpace)#1\endcsname}{%
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname(BudgetNameSpace)#1\endcsname{\inteval{(#2)}}%
  }%
  \@esphack
}%
\newcommand\ReduceBudget[2]{%
  \@bsphack
  \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname(BudgetNameSpace)#1\endcsname{%
    \inteval{(\csname(BudgetNameSpace)#1\endcsname)-(#2)}%
  }%
  \@esphack
}%
\newcommand\CurrentBudget[1]{\csname(BudgetNameSpace)#1\endcsname}%
\newcommand\Budgetlabel[2]{%
  \@bsphack\begingroup
  \Hy@localanchornametrue
  \phantomsection
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname(BudgetNameSpace)#1\endcsname}%
  \label{#2}%
  \endgroup\@esphack
}
%--Infrastructure for your scenario----------------------------------------
\InitializeNewKindOfBudget{MoneyForPieces}{1000}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcCosts}{om}{%
  % #1 label to create; #2 amount of money to withdraw from MoneyForPieces.
  \ReduceBudget{MoneyForPieces}{#2}%
  \IfNoValueF{#1}{\Budgetlabel{MoneyForPieces}{#1}}%
  Piece price:\,#2\,\CMReuro\ / Money left currently \CurrentBudget{MoneyForPieces}\,\CMReuro\ / Money left overall \ref*{overall}\,\CMReuro)
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent Budget total: \CurrentBudget{MoneyForPieces}\\
\calcCosts{3}\\
\calcCosts{30}\\
\calcCosts[overall]{400}

% Be aware that the outcome both of the command \texteuro and the unicode-
% character € is engine-dependent and differs depending on whether using
% latex, pdflatex, xelatex or  lualatex and and may probably also vary
% between different LaTeX-releases.

\LARGE
\noindent
\verb|\euro|: \euro / \verb|\texteuro|: \texteuro / \verb|\CMReuro|: \CMReuro / \verb|€|: €

\end{document}
```

This is what I get when compiling with LuaLaTeX under TeX Live 2020:

[image]

---

---

In case you wish to calculate not only with integers, but with floating-point-numbers, here is some sort of very basic routines for very basic bookkeeping:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% \euro - euro sign which complies to the symbol suggested and
% and copyrighted(!) by the European Commission -
% <https://european-union.europa.eu/institutions-law-budget/euro/design_en> :
\usepackage{eurosym}  

% Euro sign of European Computer Modern Fonts (ec - Computer
% modern fonts in T1 and TS1 encodings <https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ec>);
% in other words: Joerg Knappen's guess of what the euro sign would be:
\newcommand\CMReuro{{%
  \fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont
  \symbol{191}%
  %\texteuro
}}

\makeatletter
% A variant of \zref@setcurrent which sets properties globally
\ZREF@Robust\def\zref@setcurrentglobal#1#2{%
  \zref@propexists{#1}{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname Z@C@#1\endcsname{#2}%
  }%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOn
%
%--Generic infrastructure--------------------------------------------------
%
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \InitializeNewPostingAccount #1#2{
  \@bsphack
  \zref@newprop{PostingAccount#1}{0}
  \exp_args:Nnf
  \zref@setcurrentglobal{PostingAccount#1}{\fp_to_decimal:n{(#2)}}
  \@esphack
}%
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \WithdrawFromPostingaccount #1#2 {
  \@bsphack
  \exp_args:Nnf
  \zref@setcurrentglobal{PostingAccount#1}{
    \fp_to_decimal:n{(\zref@getcurrent{PostingAccount#1})-(#2)}
  }
  \@esphack
}%
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \SaldoOfPostingAccount #1 {
  \fp_to_decimal:n {(\zref@getcurrent{PostingAccount#1})}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \RecordSaldoOfPostingAccountToLabel #1#2 {
  \zref@labelbyprops{#2}{PostingAccount#1}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \ReferToRecordedSaldoOfPostingAccount #1#2#3 {
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#2}
    {\use_ii:nn}
    {\zref@ifrefcontainsprop{#2}{PostingAccount#1}{\use_i:nn}{\use_ii:nn}}
  {\PrintAmountOfMoney{\zref@extractdefault{#2}{PostingAccount#1}{0}}{#3}}
  {\zref@refused{#2}\textsf{??}}
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \PrintAmountOfMoney #1#2 {
  \exp_args:Nne
  \use:n {\SI [{% Adjust this according to your needs and the
                % conventions in your country - refer to the
                % documentation of siunitx:
                 add-decimal-zero,
                 add-integer-zero,
                 detect-mode=true,
                 round-integer-to-decimal=true,
                 round-mode=places,
                 round-half=up,
                 group-digits=true,  
                 group-minimum-digits=2,
                 group-separator=\,,
                 output-decimal-marker={,}, 
                 round-precision={#2}}]}
  {\fp_to_decimal:n{round(((#1)+0),#2,NaN)}}{\CMReuro}
}
%
%--Infrastructure for your scenario----------------------------------------
%
\InitializeNewPostingAccount{MoneyForPieces}{1000.24}%

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \WithdrawFromMoneyForPieces #1 {
  \WithdrawFromPostingaccount{MoneyForPieces}{#1}
  Piece~price:\nobreakspace
  \PrintAmountOfMoney{#1}{2}\nobreakspace/~
  Money~left~currently~\PrintAmountOfMoney{\SaldoOfPostingAccount{MoneyForPieces}}{2}\nobreakspace/~
  Money~left~overall~\ReferToRecordedSaldoOfPostingAccount{MoneyForPieces}{overall}{2})
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\RecordFinalMoneyForPiecesSaldoToLabel {
  \RecordSaldoOfPostingAccountToLabel{MoneyForPieces}{overall}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{1.1\textwidth}
\noindent Budget total: \PrintAmountOfMoney{\SaldoOfPostingAccount{MoneyForPieces}}{2}\\
\WithdrawFromMoneyForPieces{3.24}\\
\WithdrawFromMoneyForPieces{30}\\
\WithdrawFromMoneyForPieces{400}%
\RecordFinalMoneyForPiecesSaldoToLabel
\end{minipage}

% Be aware that the outcome both of the command \texteuro and the unicode-
% character € is engine-dependent and differs depending on whether using
% latex, pdflatex, xelatex or  lualatex and and may probably also vary
% between different LaTeX-releases.

\LARGE

\bigskip

\noindent
Some different euro sign-notations yielding different symbols:

\noindent
\verb|\euro|: \euro/ \verb|\texteuro|: \texteuro/ \verb|\CMReuro|: \CMReuro/ \verb|€|: €

\end{document}
```

This is what I get when compiling with pdfLaTeX under TeX Live 2020:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! It is exactly what I need!

Comment: Now, I try to call `\WithdrawFromMoneyForPieces{30}` inside of a `\tabbing` environment. This seems not to work. Any idea?

Comment: @PascalS I overlooked that assignments for initializing/reducing budgets/for initializing posting accounts and withdrawing money should be performed globally. (With environments, e.g., the environment tabbing, things take place within a local scope and non-global assignments won't persist beyond that scope .) This is now fixed. Sorry for not seeing this while implementing things.

Answer (score 1):

Store the overall value only once at the end of the document. I wouldn't produce links, it doesn't make much sense as there is no location associated with the overall value. Do not allocate a new counter inside your command, counters should always be allocated globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{FixMoney}
\setcounter{FixMoney}{1000}
\newcounter{SaveValue}
\setcounter{SaveValue}{\value{FixMoney}}

\newcommand{\calcCosts}[1]{%
\setcounter{SaveValue}{\inteval{\value{SaveValue}-#1}}%
Piece price:\,#1\,€ / (Money left overall \ref*{mylabel:overall}\,€)}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{shipout/lastpage}{{\def\@currentlabel{\the\value{SaveValue}}\label{mylabel:overall}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\calcCosts{3}\\
\calcCosts{30}\\
\calcCosts{400}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I was so close to the easy solution. Is there an easy way to add Floating Point functionality?

Comment: sure, use \fpeval instead of \inteval and a \fp-variable or a simply global command instead of a counter.

Comment: Can you maybe tell me, why this solution is working within the Overleaf online Tex Editor and not anymore within TeXStudio 4.5.2? Suddenly I get `Undefined Control Sequence \calcCosts{30}` and `Missing Number Treated as zero \calcCosts{30}`

Comment: perhaps your local system is too old.

Comment: Now it works again. I try to to set everything to \fp but I don't get the AddToHook cmd working. `\AddToHook{shipout/lastpage}{{\def\@currentlabel{\SaveValueFP}\label{mylabel:overall}}}` brings me to a "TeX Capacity exceeded" error.

Comment: my example works on my system, if it doesn't works for you you need to show your log-file, if you changed something and that doesn't work you need to show what you changed.

Comment: Your example works like expected :) But I'm struggling with the change to floating point calculation. Maybe you could just add this to your answer.